# Http request to local json file not working

Tags: angular

I have a very simple application where I want to display the list of products using the http get request. I am making a call to the local json file located in: 
[image]

However, I am getting the following error:

Server returned code 404, error message is: Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/api/products/products.json: 404 Not Found

here is the snapshot of my service: 
[image]

As you can see, I have specified the product url and with this productURL, I am using a httpGet to get a list of products but this request is failing by saying that the service is unable to find products.json.

a snapshot of my angular.json
[image]

Any insight on what could be the issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: register your api folder inside `angular.json` in `build` under `assets` like `app/api/product`

Comment: the api folder is already registered under assets. it is registered like this: "src/api"

Comment: you need to add this in your `angular.json` . having only folder inside src will not  registered under assets. you need to tell angular explicitly to use the json present inside product folder in build time. So in `angular.json` you need to add one more entry in `build --> assets` object

Comment: please share your `angular.json`

Comment: I have added a snapshot in my original query. I have tried it your way and it still doesn't display the list of products

Answer (score 1):

register your api folder in angular.json

```
...
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/app/api/products" // Forgot to add app here..now chk if its working
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/montserrat/montserrat.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [

            ]
             ...
```

Make sure you restart server after making changes in angular.json

**else** add your API folder inside assets folder in your project
 DEMO : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jvascy

Comment: @MahadevanSwamy try moving your api folder inside assets folder... and then use path like `assets/api/products/products.json`

Comment: Please see the added stackblitz URL